# Is possible to create a navigation notification from application context to view in android auto head unit

Tags: android, android-auto

I am trying to create a navigation notification android auto screen from the mobile app context.  I tried the following code from main activity to trigger the notification. but it only shows on the mobile.

```
    private void sendNotification(CharSequence title, CharSequence text, String channelId,
                              CharSequence channelName, int notificationId, int importance) {
    CarNotificationManager carNotificationManager =
            CarNotificationManager.from(this);

    NotificationChannelCompat channel = new NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(channelId,
            importance).setName(channelName).build();
    carNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);

    builder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_NAVIGATION);
    builder.setOngoing(true);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title + " (phone)")
            .setContentText(text + " (phone)")
            .setColor(getColor(androidx.car.app.R.color.carColorGreen))
            .setColorized(true)
            .setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
            .addAction(
                    new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                            "Action1 (phone)",
                            createPendingIntent(INTENT_ACTION_PRIMARY_PHONE))
                            .build())
            .addAction(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                    "Action2 (phone)",
                    createPendingIntent(INTENT_ACTION_SECONDARY_PHONE))
            .extend(
                    new CarAppExtender.Builder()
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setColor(CarColor.PRIMARY)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                            .setLargeIcon(
                                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                            getResources(),
                                            R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                            .addAction(
                                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                                    "navigate",
                                    getPendingIntentForNavigation())
                            .addAction(
                                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                                    "ti",
                                    createPendingIntentForCall())
                            .build());

    carNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder);
}


    private PendingIntent createPendingIntentForCall() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:+14257232350"));
    return CarPendingIntent.getCarApp(this, intent.hashCode(), intent, 0);
}


/**
 * Returns a pending intent with the provided intent action.
 */
private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(String intentAction) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentAction);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, intentAction.hashCode(), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntentForNavigation() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE).setData(Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Home"));
    return CarPendingIntent.getCarApp(this, intent.hashCode(), intent, 0);
}
```

Here I tried set type as navigation. Also set other requirements for the navigation notification .